# Monitor queries in an access database

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to monitor queries in an access database, similar to the way SQL Profiler works?

I have a very old piece of software that I do not have the source for and it has an ODBC connection to an access database on another computer.  Is there a way to monitor what queries are being called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried turning on the ODBC trace function?  Use the ODBC Data Sources control panel applet.  Switch to the 'Trace' tab and review the options available.

Comment: Horray!  That works!!!  Gives a little too much information and too few options, but the data is there!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a tool that does that - but I can suggest two simple ways of doing this:

1. Set-up a proxy so that your queries go to the proxy, the proxy logs them and then forwards them to the access database
2. do a tcp-dump and extract the queries (monitor what happens at the wire level).

Answer (score 1):

You might also find Jet SHOWPLAN useful:

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5064388.html

Comment: + but one downside is that the output file appears in the current folder, hence I have showplan.out files all over my file system (grr).